# App freezes after dismiss Viewcontroller when showing Webview in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, webview, arkit

I'm showing a webview in AR using ARKit.

```
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 480), configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.fritz-kola.de")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
```

Then I use the Webview as content for my SCNNode to be displayed in AR.

```
    let tvPlane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1,height: 0.1)
    tvPlane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.webView
    let tvPlaneNode = SCNNode(geometry: tvPlane)
    tvPlaneNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    node.addChildNode(tvPlaneNode)
```

By calling `self.dismiss(...)` The ARScreen dismisses, though the app freezes.

This is my `viewwilldisappear` function:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    session.pause()
}
```

Comment: Same issue. This happens whenever I try to add custom views to the SceneKit Nodes. If I don't do this navigation to the previous screen works without problems. Have you been able to figure out a solution?

Comment: I have same problem when navigate to another screen. Have you find any solution for this. please let me know ?

Comment: I've only managed to avoid this by using the depreciated UIWebView. I am not sure why exactly this is happening though. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview

Comment: @MikeKoene i am also facing same issue. have you found any solution ?

Comment: @MehulD I avoided this issue by using the depreciated UIWebView.